# parser creation in perl that extract xml tags from source code?

Tags: perl

i have to extract xml comments from c code .I tried using perl regexp but i am unable to extract the comments. can any one help me. my code as shown below.

```
   Dima_chkTimeValidation(&dacl_ts_pumpPWMLowNoDos_str,
                       &dacl_ti_pumpPWMLowNoDos_U16,
                       ti_valid_U16,
                       ti_inval_U16,
                       (tB)(dacl_r_pumpPwmResidualFilt_S16 < r_testlimit_S16),
                       (tB)((testCond_B == TRUE) && (dosingActive_B == FALSE)),
                       TRUE);
  /*****************************************/
  /*xml comments*/
  /****************************************/

 <DTC>
  <TroubleCode>1101</TroubleCode> 
  <Classification>FAULT</Classification> 
  <SelfHealing>No selfhealing</SelfHealing> 
  <WarningLamp>No Warning Lamp</WarningLamp> 
  <DirectDegradation>No Action</DirectDegradation> 
  <Order>PRIMARY</Order> 
   </DTC>
     /*******************************/
  /* Dosing clogg test           */
  /*******************************/
  /* special test when run i sequence test mode SMHD_DOSVALVE_E */
  if ((s_seqTestCtrlStatus_E == SMHD_RUNNING_E) && (s_seqTestMainState_SMHD_DOSVALVE_E))
  {
    /* Use result from DDOS test */
    Dima_chkValidation(&dacl_ts_pumpPWMLowDos_str,
                       (tB)(s_dosValveTest_E == SMHD_TESTFAILED_E),
                       (tB)(s_dosValveTest_E != SMHD_TESTNOTFINISHED_E));
   }
```

as show above i have lot of c code lines before and after xml comments but i posted just little c code, i added some comments in the c code, i need to extract the comments as it is. so any body can help me how to extract using perl.

Comment: Your "code" does NOT contain any XML!

Comment: Hi my source code is a combination of c code and xml comments. my code having xml comments.

Comment: XML comments are delimited with <!-- cooment here -->. You do not have any XML comments in what you've shown us. End tags in XML have a slash after the < as in <dtcnumber>1223</dtcnumber>. You do not have XML end tags, therefore you do not have XML.

Comment: Hi, sorry for wrong posting,now i am reposting the question can see below

Comment: Hi, sorry. my xml comments like <dtc>1223</dtc> but format is like this  c code .......xml comments...........c code so i need to extract xml code part. i have 10 lines of xml comments like above mentioned . can u tel me how to extract in perl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not a good idea to write the whole code for your work, but I am still doing it so that you can get an idea of how to approach a particular problem.

Here, I am providing you the simplest approach (might not be efficient)

1. Keep you input data simple and make your life more simpler. Identify a particular pattern using which your code can identify the beginning and end of XML.

```
Dima_chkTimeValidation(&dacl_ts_pumpPWMLowNoDos_str,
                       &dacl_ti_pumpPWMLowNoDos_U16,
                       ti_valid_U16,
                       ti_inval_U16,
                       (tB)(dacl_r_pumpPwmResidualFilt_S16 <  r_testlimit_S16),
                       (tB)((testCond_B == TRUE) && (dosingActive_B == FALSE)),
                       TRUE);
  /*****************************************/

  /*[[[ Start XML  

 < DTC >
  < TroubleCode > 1101 < /TroubleCode > 
  < Classification > FAULT < /Classification > 
  < SelfHealing > No selfhealing < /SelfHealing > 
  < WarningLamp > No Warning Lamp lt /WarningLamp > 
  < DirectDegradation > No Action < /DirectDegradation > 
  < Order > PRIMARY < /Order > 
   < /DTC >

   End XML]]]*/

  /*******************************/


  /* special test when run i sequence test mode SMHD_DOSVALVE_E */
  if ((s_seqTestCtrlStatus_E == SMHD_RUNNING_E) && (s_seqTestMainState_SMHD_DOSVALVE_E))
  {
    /* Use result from DDOS test */
    Dima_chkValidation(&dacl_ts_pumpPWMLowDos_str,
                       (tB)(s_dosValveTest_E == SMHD_TESTFAILED_E),
                       (tB)(s_dosValveTest_E != SMHD_TESTNOTFINISHED_E));
   }
```

Here, you can identify the pattern I have kept to detect starting of xml and end of xml

2. Next, is the code. Now i have tried to write it as much in the "C" way except for the regex.

`#!/usr/bin/perl
#
#
open(FD,"< Code.cpp") or die "unable to open file: $!\n";

my $start_xml = 0 ; ## 0 indicates false condition ..i.e either XML not started or XML ended
                    ## 1 means xml has started.

while(< FD >){

        chomp($_);

        ## Handling only single Line comments

        my $temp = $_;

        if($temp =~ m/\[\[\[\s*start\s*xml/ig && $start_xml == 0){  ## Check if start xml pattern found

                $start_xml = 1;
                next;     ## equivalent to continue of C 
        }

        if(($temp =~ m/< [a-z0-9 -&!@]+ >.*/ig)  && ($start_xml == 1)){ ## You can add additional letters that may come
                                                              ## In such cases pattern matching wont be necessary as you know
                                                              # you have got XML data between start and end xml pattern. But still... 
                                                              #  some case you might need it

                print "$temp\n";  ## I am printing it out , but you may write it to file

        }elsif($temp =~ m/end\s*xml\s*\]\]\]/ig){

                $start_xml = 0;
                last;   ## equivalent to break in C
        }
}
close FD;`

**NOTE ::**  There is no < space > after "<" and after the ">" tag in the text and in the code. So, remove that space when you are running the code.

The kind of pattern chosen to detect xml taken from "Python cog" :)

Comment: Hi, frist of all thank you very much and now i got some idea. i will try like this.

Comment: Hi this code is not excuted, i am getting use of unintilized $_ error . i tried to intilize $line= $_; but still getting error.

Comment: i am getting error like use of unintilized $_ in scalar chomp and pattran matching. can u help me to aviod this error

Comment: just before the if branch save $_ into another variable and use that variable instead of $_,  <code>$temp = $_; </code>

Comment: open(File, "ccode.c") or die "unable to open file: $!\n"; while(<File>) { $temp=$_; chomp($temp); if($temp=~ m/\/\/<[a-z0-9_*.]*>/ig){ $temp=~ s/\/\///g; print "$temp\n"; } } ##print "$temp\n"; close (File);

Comment: hi, if you dnt mine can you have a look at my second question "extracrt comments from code". but that one is closed by stackoverflow due to duplicate post. i posted my total code in that question so some where its match with previous question. so can you solve my problem. can you help me extract xml comments from that code. can you give the code to extract xml comments.

Comment: sorry i added my code in this post itself can you have a look at my code.pls bcz i am beginer, i am understanding little bit now. can u help me.

Comment: @verendra : You got what you want ? Now its time to accept any one of the answer. You have to accept answers if you want in future community people to help you out

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your helping, now i understand how to solve problems. sorry for asking the hole code,because i am beginer so i feel tension and i asked like that. once again thank you very much and i tried your code.its excuting correctly.i got what i want, my problem sovled. thanks for stackoverflow forum.

Answer (score 4):

Your data is bizarre, to say the least. I'm making two assumptions here: the `'` is the starting delimiter of the example string, and you want to extract the stuff between the angle brackets (which are neither XML nor XML comments according to, you know, the standard). No guarantee against misparsing embedded C code.

```
use 5.010;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

say Dumper \%+ while
'<dtcnumber>1223<dtcnumber>
 <discription>battery short circuited<discription>
   <cause>due to unproper connections<cause>
  main();
  {
   ..........
   ...
   c code.
   ...
    };' =~ /<(?<key>[^>]+)>(?<value>[^<]+)<\g{key}>/g;
```

---

Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'value' => '1223',
          'key' => 'dtcnumber'
        };

$VAR1 = {
          'value' => 'battery short circuited',
          'key' => 'discription'
        };

$VAR1 = {
          'value' => 'due to unproper connections',
          'key' => 'cause'
        };
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you very much for your reply, i got some idea and i will try like this as you mentioned above.